# Img width does not extend to width of table tag

Tags: html

I am writing an HTML newsletter and for some reason my img width does not extend the full width of the td tag despite having the same pixel width. My image shows up as 180, but the width of the td tag is 186. provided below is my code.

```
<table width="600" bgcolor="#ffffff" height="30" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr >
        <td width="10"></td>
        <td width="180" height="30" bgcolor="#000000"><p style="text-align:center; color:#ffffff">ALONSOS</p></td>
        <td width="10"></td>
        <td width="180" bgcolor="#000000"><p style="text-align:center; color:#ffffff">ZEN WEST</p></td>
        <td width="10"></td>
        <td width="180" bgcolor="#000000"><p style="text-align:center; color:#ffffff">LUCKIE'S TAVERN</p></td>
        <td width="10"></td>

    <tr>
        <td width="10"></td>
        <td width="180" height="30" bgcolor="#ffffff"><img src="zenwest.png" width="180"/></td>
        <td width="10"></td>
        <td width="180" height="30" bgcolor="#000000"><img src="zenwest.png" width="180"/></td>
        <td width="10"></td>
        <td width="180" bgcolor="#000000"><img src="magerks.png" width="180" /></td>
        <td width="10"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="10"></td>
        <td width="180" ><p><b>Saturday, Feb. 9th</b></p>
            <p>$3 Bud Light</p>
            <p>$4 Soco & Lime</p>
            <p>$3 Bud Light</p>
        </td>
        <td width="10"></td>
        <td width="176"><p><b>Saturday, Feb. 9th</b></p>
            <p>$3 Bud Light</p>
            <p>$4 Soco & Lime</p>
            <p>$3 Bud Light</p>
        </td>
        <td width="10"></td>
        <td width="180"><p><b>Saturday, Feb. 9th</b></p>
            <p>$3 Bud Light</p>
            <p>$4 Soco & Lime</p>
            <p>$3 Bud Light</p>
        </td>
        <td width="10"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You have a height of 30 set on your table tag - is that meant to be there? You'r first TR has no closing TR tag. You only really need to set the widths on the first row of TD tags. Some of your later TD widths don't match up to earlier ones. You should set a height on your images too. It's slightly risky using PNG images in emails. Best to stick to JPG or GIF format. I'd also recommend using <strong> rather than <b>. That's all for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`table-cell` width is similar to `display: inline` in that it does not necessarily respect the provided width, and in this case it depends on the table.  The table cell widths will increase to fit the width of the entire `600px`-wide table, resulting in the seemingly odd behavior you are seeing.  You can either increase the in-between `<td>`s such that the total widths add up to 600, or you can remove the table width and have it be whatever it's going to be (something like `580px`).

Answer (score 0):

All the td tags in your markup have '180' width. Try setting the preferred td tag's width to '186'.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Thanks j09691, I have made it more answer-like now.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the width on the table the spacing ends up the way you want it.

```
<table bgcolor="#ffffff" height="30" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/WaVZv/)**